# ansible string to variable (aka eval)

Tags: ansible

I have a list of strings `strs = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]` and some dicts `foo = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, bar = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}`.  I'd like to use with_items to index into the named dicts

```
- copy
  src: {{item}}.a
  dest: {{item}}.b
  with_items: strs
```

But I want {{item}}  to refer to the variables named foo and bar rather than the strings.  In lisp or python I'd use `eval` for this.  Is there something similar in ansible?

Answer (score 3):

Why not set a dictionary and loop through it using `with_dict`?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    strs:
      foo:
        a: 1
        b: 2
      bar:
        a: 3
        b: 4

  tasks:
  - copy: src={{ item.value.a }} dest={{ item.value.b }}
    with_dict: strs
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he needed something more dynamic as follow.

This is possible with 2.1.
I needed to get the subset of a hash having an array of some of the hash keys, I stumbled about this post, then I found a solution.

I use [that](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers).

I choose to provide a completely silly and useless but complete example.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    filenames: [ file1, file2 ]
    file1:
      a: file1.c
      b: file1.o
    file2:
      a: file2.c
      b: file2.o
    file3:
      a: file3.py
      b: file3.pyc
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="gcc -c -o {{item.b}} {{item.a}}"
      with_items: 
        - "{{ filenames | map('extract', vars) | list}}"
```

The output of ansible-playbook this is:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'a': u'file1.c', u'b': u'file1.o'}) => {
    "item": {
        "a": "file1.c", 
        "b": "file1.o"
    }, 
    "msg": "gcc -c -o file1.o file1.c"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'a': u'file2.c', u'b': u'file2.o'}) => {
    "item": {
        "a": "file2.c", 
        "b": "file2.o"
    }, 
    "msg": "gcc -c -o file2.o file2.c"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I'm interested in feedbacks.